# No commits available for merging in the Git request

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-commit

I merged a branch, lets say `developer` in to another branch lets say `main`.

Then I realized that the changes from `developer` were not meant to be available in `main`.

I used the `remove branch` option that created a merge request excluding my changes from `main` branch. I merged this request and the `main` branch no longer contained changes from `developer`, while the `developer` branch remained as it was.

However, after few days I want those changes to be available in `main`, I tried creating new merge request from `developer` to `main`. This request displays no commits to be merged.

Perhaps the commit were earlier merged in to `main` branch and Git now do not recognize them as new commit (although they were reverted).

What is the way of merging the changes available in `developer` to 'main` now ?

Comment: Just a note. In a git example with fake names, it's a bit clumsy to use `local` as a branch name. What will be its upstream counterpart? *remote* `local`? Confusing to say the least.

Comment: You will have to revert the revert. Then, if you have further changes in developer after the original merge, you can merge those into main afterwards.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Well received. I changed the branch name from local to developer.

Comment: Thanks @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Will try this out.

Comment: If you want to ensure your final merge is a-ok you can create a new branch from main, revert the revert *on this branch*, then merge developer into this branch, and do final testing, verification, before you merge this new branch into main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps you will have to take can be summarized as follows (note that I will outline first the way you probably want to do it, and then afterwards outline the steps that are *required*):

Here's how you should do it:

1. From main, create and check out a new temporary branch to stabilize the merges

   ```
   git checkout main
   git checkout -b temp-merges
   ```
2. Revert your revert, *on this new branch*

   ```
   git revert SHA-OF-PREVIOUS-REVERT
   ```
3. If you have further changes in developer after the original merge, you can merge developer into this new temporary branch as well

   ```
   git merge developer
   ```
4. Verify the end-result, that it satisfies whatever acceptance criteria you have, like running unit-tests, building the code, ensuring no merge conflicts, etc.
5. Finally merge the temporary branch into main, accepting the results

   ```
   git checkout main
   git merge temp-merges
   ```
6. Delete the temporary branch

   ```
   git branch -d temp-merges
   ```

Now, this allows you to verify the results before finally merging into main.

Before the final merge, here's how your branches will look

```
        developer
            v
1--2--3--4--5--------------------+
       \                          \
        \                 (-(-D))--G 
         \               /         ^
          \             /      temp-merges
  A--B--C--D--(-D)--E--F
                       ^
                      main
```

---

If you don't need to do this, or can do it locally on the main branch before pushing, the *required* steps are simply:

1. Revert the revert, on the main branch

   ```
   git revert SHA-OF-PREVIOUS-REVERT
   ```
2. If you have further changes in developer after the original merge, you can merge developer into main branch as well

   ```
   git merge developer
   ```
3. Verify, if necessary

---

If your situation is just that you have no changes on developer after the original merge, you only have to do this:

1. Revert the revert, on the main branch

   ```
   git revert SHA-OF-PREVIOUS-REVERT
   ```

and call it a day.

Comment: That was a pretty detailed answer man. Thanks for your time. However, luckily I had no further changes after original merge. So I believe I can go with your latter approach.